# More than 4 images below the main image in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am using the Debut theme and I would like to know how can I have more than 4 images below the main image.
The image below is for example only.
[image]

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide us with the code of the section and what have you tried on your own to fix the issue.

Comment: What I want is put all the images under the main image in the same row.

Comment: StackOverflow is a platform to help developers with their code issues, it's not to provide a free code to users. If you don't show us the code that you've tried to implement this section we assume that you are looking for free coding service which the community here doesn't provide. You must provided a minimum effort, a.k.a show us the section code and what issues do you have with it. ( so only copy/pasting the code is not a proper question as well ) If you don't understand the code at all then SO is the wrong platform for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this code I achieved what I needed.

```
.product-single__thumbnails-item--medium {
  @include media-query($medium-up) {
    flex: 0 0 percentage(1 / 3);
  }

  @include media-query($large-up) {
    flex: 0 0 15%;
  }
}
```

In the theme.scss.liquid file look for a code fragment like the one above, the flex property will be 0 0 25%, which means that there will be 4 images under the main one. Just change the percentage according to your needs. In my case I put it on 15%.